# Can anyone think of a better term than "verismo-ists"?

Tags: single-word-requests

*Verismo* was a movement in art.

It was also a very powerful movement in opera, giving us such excellent composers as Giacomo Puccini and Rugero Leoncavallo.

The word *verismo* comes from *vero*, i.e. "truth," meaning that the participants of the movement strived to make their music sound as close to real life as possible.

No matter.

Now:

Composers who are thought to be followers of Richard Wagner are called *Wagnerists*.

Wagner's most ardent fans are called *Wagnerites*.

Authors who emphasize writing and narrative style in their words are stylists. Or something.

Authors whose forte is to write sentimental stories are *sentimentalists*.

And so forth.

Now, verismo composers are sometimes referred to as verismo-ists, but this sounds a bit awkward to me.

Can you think of a better term?

Comment: Use the original root and call them all _Verists_.

Comment: In Italian the term is ***verista***  which is translated as ***verist*** https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_inglese/Italiano/V/verista.shtml - https://www.lexico.com/definition/verist

Comment: Verismo is the Italian name of a larger artistic European trend known as Realism. The Britannica says: *Giacomo Puccini... Italian composer, **one of the greatest exponents of operatic realism**, who virtually brought the history of Italian opera to an end.*  https://www.britannica.com/biography/Giacomo-Puccini  In that sense also the term ***realist*** may apply: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/realist

Answer (score 1):

No. If that's what's used, use it.

Eventually the hyphen will probably disappear. But if most other people use it now, you should, too.